# Check su exists i.e. Device is rooted or not

Tags: android, superuser

This question is possibly a duplicate but I have gone through all the answers and noticed that they won't be working anymore.

```
 private static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
    return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
}
```

Method-1 failed

```
 private static boolean checkRootMethod2() {
    String[] paths = { "/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su",
            "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su" };
    for (String path : paths) {
        if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Method 2 also failed because "SuperSu" is not system app anymore it can be uninstall and su file is now present on separate folder SU/bin/su

```
private static boolean checkRootMethod3() {
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/which", "su" });
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        if (in.readLine() != null) return true;
        return false;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (process != null) process.destroy();
    }
}
```

method 3 also failed because there is no "which" file on android devices nowadays

```
RootTools.isavailable();
```

also failed

My question is can I detect device rooted by checking whether the su file is inside the Su/bin/su folder? Is this the right way to detect rooted device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add "/su/bin/su" to paths variable of checkRootMethod2()
2. as to method 3, you should also call "which" by using "/system/bin/which"

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sam Lu but you are little late ;)

Comment: "which" file is not exists now a days not even at "/system/bin/which" path